# Clicking on Android home button should not close the app, instead it should run a custom function in flutter

Tags: android

https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6J5L.png

When I click on this button, Its closing the application. Here I want to add a custom function, so instead of closing the application, it run a custom function in flutter. How can I do that??

Comment: You, luckily, cannot. Unless you rooted anyway.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski but when you press the button in google map, this will trigger picture in picture mode, instead of closing the app and its not rooted too...how?

Comment: it's system feature, not app's. It declares to support PiP and then things go that way, but you cannot intercept HOME button in your app.